# Is there a way to use ARCore for projection based AR?

Tags: arcore

I am trying to implement a projection based AR prototype which is meant to detect and track QR markers on a surface and projects corresponding images next to them simultaneously. I know the first part of the project is possible using ARCore but I was wondering if there is a way to send AR output to a projector instead of a phone screen. If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need AR for this - you can simply have your detection trigger a regular image to be projected to the surface you want:

- QR reader / Phone etc detects QR code and sends message to 'controller'
- Controller recognises code and sends message to directly connected or network connected projector
- Projector projects image onto screen/surface

You do obviously have to have some sort of screen or surface to project the image onto, unless you are thinking of 3D models in which case you would need something like a Holographic Projector.

Comment: Hi Mick, thank you for answering. I understand however I need the projector to be projecting different images for different markers simultaneously in the same projection space. This is why I thought an AR library such ARCore would be ideal. However, if it still isn't, what tech stack would you recommend I use?

Comment: @VictorAntony - if the user is looking through a screen, like a phone or glasses or headset, and can see the room etc around them as well as images you add to the screen then AR on the device is the right technology. If you just want to add objects projected into the real room or wherever they are that they can see directly, then you need some sort of projector solution and unfortunately you probably need a projector, or even holographic projector, per marker by the sounds of your requirements.